# MVC, show modal content dependent on dropdown (ajax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have no idea how to do something like this.
I have a dropdown with six element, and button.
When I click butto I want to show bootstrap modalpopup. It's a simple.
But I want to tt depends on the selection drop down.

My view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-addCompanyRisk">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
            </button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-addCompanyRisk" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="allCustomerModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">

                 [... Load index from other view...]
                    <div class="modal-body">                            
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@Resources.Common.Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the content of the list which is to settle on a modal should be dependent on the dropdown.
If the backet all form and button (class="btn btn-default") is a submit, then I dont know how show modal from ActionResult(controller)

**EDIT**

Partially I solved my problem.
I add to dropdown Ajax.BeginForm and submit

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetAllRiskForCompanu", "InsuranceCompanyRisks", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
    }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InsuranceCompanyId, ViewBag.InsuranceCompany as SelectList, @Resources.Common.Select, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsuranceCompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    }
```

on controller write method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Void GetAllRiskForCompanu(FormCollection form)
{
    int? companyId = form["InsuranceCompanyId"].GetNullableInt();

    if (companyId.HasValue)
    {
        //set session varible
        InsurancePolicySession.InsuranceCompanyRisks = icrf.GetAll(companyId.Value);
    }

}
```

by button add I show modala with render partialView

```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/InsurancePolicyItem/IndexPolicyCompanyRisk.cshtml", @InsurancePolicySession.InsuranceCompanyRisks)
```

when I change dropdown selected value the session refresh but when I show modal still view old value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess around with an AjaxForm and directly manipulating a Bootstrap modal, you might find it easier to use something like [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com), which will generate your Bootstrap modal as needed.

I would use a normal form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id="some-id", role="form" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeId, Model.Somethings, new { @class="form-control" })
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```

Then, capture the form submission and do an Ajax request to get your content:

```
$(function(){

    $('#some-id').on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal form submit

        var form = $(this);
        var data = form.serialize();

        $.post(form.attr('action'), data)
            .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){
                // handle response...
            })
    })
})
```

Inside the success handler (`.done()`), build up your dialog. Bootbox has built-in functions for alert, confirm, and prompt (it's primary purpose is to mostly replicate those native functions), but you'll probably want to use `dialog()`, which lets you completely customize the modal. You'll want to [read the documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html) to get the most out of it, but a basic usage could be (starting from where you see `// handle response...` above):

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    title: 'Some Title',
    message: response,
    buttons: {

        cancel: {
            label: 'Cancel',
            className: 'btn-default',
            callback: function(){
                dialog.modal('hide');
            }
        },

        save: {
            label: 'Submit',
            className: 'btn-primary',
            callback: function(){
                // submit your data from the injected content, somehow...
            }
        }

    }
});
```

I primarily use Bootbox at this point, simply because I find it easier than having the modal template on the page. I've also run into the same issue you seem to be having, which is that a reused modal doesn't seem to want to update it's content.

**Disclaimer:** I am currently a collaborator on the Bootbox project, although I am mostly there to keep the documentation up to date and triage issues.